# How to embed iframe from google map engine into wordpress.com?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-engine

I would like to to embed an iframe object from google map engine (specifically, [a landsat annual timelapse](https://earthengine.google.org/#timelapse/v=-12.97805,-70.51164,9.853,latLng&t=2.87)) into my wordpress.com blog. Wordpress.com generally does no accept iframes, but it does generate special shortcodes for some sites, including google maps.

When I paste the following iframe into the text edit space in wordpress.cow:

```
    <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://earthengine.google.org/timelapse/player?c=https%3A%2F%2Fearthengine.google.org%2Ftimelapse%2Fdata&v=-12.97805,-70.51164,9.5&r=.25&p=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Wordpress.com generates the following shortcode:

```
    [googlemaps https://maps.google.org/timelapse/player?c=https%3A%2F%2Fearthengine.google.org%2Ftimelapse%2Fdata&amp;v=-12.97805,-70.51164,9.5&amp;r=.25&amp;p=true&amp;w=854&amp;h=480]
```

However, when I preview my post, there is no map animation. Instead, there is a gray box with this message "unable to resolve the server's DNS address".

I am able to embed maps from google maps into my blog. The problem arises only with the google map engine landsat animation.

Can anyone assist me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like whatever is doing the  to [googlemaps] conversion thinks that your iframe is for a Google Maps embedded map, which is not correct as the frame you're embedding is a purpose-build web page.

You'll need to either find that plugin in your wordpress installation and disable it, or worst case, find the author of the plugin and report it to them as a bug.